# How can I make my inner table show?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this, all rows have the structure like 1st data row

```
<table id='table1'>
   <thead>
       <tr>...table headers...</tr>
  </thead>
   <tr>
       <td>xyz</td>
       <td>
           <table><tr></tr></table>
       </td>
   </tr>

   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
   ...
   ...
</table>
```

All those inside tables have some texts and images.

Initially, I use

```
$('#table1').find("tr:gt(0)").hide();
```

to hide everything except header

Now I want to select say from row 1 to row 15 and unhide them. From another post, I know I can use
`$('#table1').children('tr').slice(1,15)` to find those rows, but when I want to show them using

```
$('#table1').children('tr').slice(1,15).show(1000);
```

all those inside tables are still not showing, but the text "xyz" is showed Am I missing something here?

Comment: do you have control over the HTML? If so, how about adding various CSS classes to the tables so you can differentiate between them in your selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tr` are not `.children` of table, but descendants because they are inside an implicitly created `tbody` element. Try with `.children()` of the `tbody`

http://jsfiddle.net/utmXa/4/

```
$('#table1 > tbody').children().hide();
$('#table1 > tbody').children().slice(1, 15).show(1000);
```

Comment: wouldn't this find all inner tables <tr>, and when you slice(1,15), you will end up selecting less that 15 rows?